# "Financial limitation" or "financial capacity"

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct if I say in this way to express the reason why I can not attend an activity:

> Due to the **financial limitation** I couldn’t attend this training.

Comment: How about: *I don't have the money*? No need to use the difficult words.

Comment: Or the **funding**, if it is related to business or a job.

Comment: If the other person knows about your finantial limitations, then yes. Otherwice you'd have to omit the definite article: due to finantial limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Without context, the definite article looks strange. What financial limitation? Does the venue require you have a certain salary to attend this training? Are you forced to pay for the training yourself and your budget can't handle it? Does a third party (your company, perhaps) not have the liquid assets to justify this expense? If you're being intentionally vague, omit the definite article. Otherwise, use 'their', 'my', or 'our'.